# using the "mouseover" option to htlatex gives error: "missing file xhtex":

Tags: tex4ht, htlatex

I would like to use the mouseover option to htlatex, but it seems the file is missing from the texlive distribution. I have tried to find it, but it doesn't seem to exist anywhere any longer. Does anyone know where I can find this or have a replacement?

Comment: Could you please post a minimal TeX file which shows this issue?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `mouseover` option needs to postprocess generated file with `xhtex` command, which is Plain TeX variant of `htlatex`. This command isn't included in TeX Live, but it can be emulated using `mk4ht xhtex` instead.

Fortunately, `mouseover` option can be configured using various options:

```
--- Note --- Option `mouseover' is powered by the overlib.js utility of Erik Bo
srup (http://www.bosrup.com/web/overlib/).
--------------------------------------

The option requires two compilations of the source file.

Use \Configure{mouseover-XXX}{...} to introduce extra arguments into the overli
b function call `return overlib(...)'. XXX stands for `cite', `footnote', or 'g
loss'. The default body is at tex4ht.body, and the default caption at tex4ht.ca
ption. An empty parameter requests no sensitivity of the mouse for the specifie
d type of entries.

The variant \Configure{mouseover-XXX}[labels]{...} of the above command restric
ts the outcome just to the listed labels (i.e., the values listed in tex4ht.cap
tion).

The \Configure{mouseover-script}{variable-name} {javascript-code} command may b
e used to introduce code into the javascript file, as a content of a global var
iable when a name is given and as a bare code when the name is not given. To be
 referenced, the name must be prefixed by ``tex4ht.'.

The \Configure{mouseover-vars}{XXX} {variable-list} command introduces local va
riables, to be referenced with the prefix ``tex4ht.' on their names. In additio
n, for each variable YYY it introduces a construct \moYYY{label}...\endmoYYY fo
r selecting a value for the variable at the specified label.

Example:
 \Configure{mouseover-script}{var}{\relax \special {t4ht=<hr />}}
\Configure{mouseover-vars}{cite}{Author,Title}
\Configure{mouseover-cite} {tex4ht.body,CAPTION,tex4ht.caption+tex4ht.var,FULLH
TML}.
 \moAuthor{bb}A name\endmoAuthor

The compilation indirectly invokes the command 'xhtex \jobname-js'. An alternat
ive format for the command can be requested within a configuration of the form 
\Configure{mouseover-Needs}{\Needs{"..."}}. The default setting is due to \Conf
igure{mouseover-Needs}{\Needs{"xhtex \jobname-js"}}
In case \Configure{mouseover-Needs} is undefined, introduce the instruction \Ne
wConfigure{mouseover-Needs}{1} before that command.
```

From these options, `mouseover-Needs` seems most important, because it enables us to define different command for the post-processing. You can create a simple configuration file, `mycfg.cfg`:

```
\Preamble{xhtml,mouseover}
\Configure{mouseover-Needs}{\Needs{"mk4ht xhtex \jobname-js"}}
\begin{document}

\EndPreamble
```

You will also need to put [overlib.js](https://github.com/overlib/overlib) to the directory with your HTML files. You can then compile your file using:

```
make4ht -c mycfg.cfg filename.tex
```

Sample file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
Some text\footnote{this is a footnote}.
\end{document}
```

It will be rendered like this:

[image]